# htaccess to strip www and force SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have what I believe to be a rather well crafted .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This says to me "strip the www. off the url and force https."  And it works fine except for those people who happen to type in https://www.somedomain.com/.  Those people are presented with a warning that there is a problem with the site certificate.  It seems that the www is not getting stripped in this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually combine both rules into one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Then make sure to clear your browser cache to test this.

However just remember that certificate negotiation between web server and browser happens before `mod_rewrite` is invoked.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, given that certificate negotiation happens before mod_rewrite, is there any solution for those users who are stuck on typing www?  Do I need to buy wildcard certificates for every domain?

Comment: I believe most of the SSL certificates support both `www` and non-www.

Comment: Well, re-installing the certificate on the domain seems to have fixed it.  Go figure.  You have earned a checkmark sir.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon, I'm still getting the same behaviour.  But I have to renew it next week anyway.  You may retain your checkmark for providing clarity ;)

Comment: Super helpful to me, 2 years later. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I now get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` saying my example.com is redirecting me too many times. ???

Comment: @danfo: I am using this exact rule on few live websites and it works fine. `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` mean some other rule/config/code in your site is either adding `www` or `http://`

Comment: this seems does not seem to work with `http://www.*` because it just redirects to  `https://www.*`

Comment: @Nosajimiki: This rule removes `www`. Test it independently from a new browser.

Comment: Ah thanks, I did a hard refresh + clear cache which did not work, but restarting my browser did.  Thanks.