# Redirect with .htaccess how to bind correct?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

Hello I have a next htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But a problem is when I open https://www.somesite.com it doesn't redirect to https://somesite.com. How can I get rid of this "www"?

Comment: There are many questions like this, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.htaccess%5D+strip+www

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess to strip www and force SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059495/htaccess-to-strip-www-and-force-ssl)